# DAO code for Microsoft access works in Visual Studio 2008 but not in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ms-access

I have the following line of code in an example project I downloaded and opened in Visual Studio 2008

```
_bstr_t bstrConnect = "PATH to MDB file";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout<<DAM<<": Failed to CoInitialize() COM."<<endl;
    return hr;
}

DAO::_DBEngine* pEngine = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstance(
    __uuidof(DAO::DBEngine),
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL,
    IID_IDispatch,
    (LPVOID*)&pEngine);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pEngine)
{
    try
    {
        DAO::DatabasePtr pDbPtr = NULL;
        pDbPtr = pEngine->OpenDatabase(bstrConnect);
```

This code works.  I then put some very similar code in a Visual Studio 2012 project

```
_bstr_t bstrConnect = "PATH to MDB file";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout<<"Failed to CoInitialize() COM."<<endl;
    cout << _com_error(hr).ErrorMessage() << endl;
    return hr;
}

DAO::_DBEngine* pEngine = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstance(
    __uuidof(DAO::DBEngine),
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL,
    IID_IDispatch,
    (LPVOID*)&pEngine);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pEngine)
{
    try
    {
        DAO::DatabasePtr pDbPtr = NULL;
        pDbPtr = pEngine->OpenDatabase(bstrConnect);
```

In the 2012 version I get a System.AccessViolationException when I call pEngine->OpenDatabase.  Is there something I need to change in the 2012 code? I originally had CoInitialize in the 2012 version but it kept returning an error until I switched to CoInitializeEx.

Comment: Why would you be trying to use DAO in .NET? DAO has been (more or less) obsolete before .NET 1.0 was even released.

Comment: I suggest you query for the actual interface type of your prospect pointer rather than asking for `IID_IDispatch` and hoping you get back something with all the methods afterward. By definition, you asked for `IID_IDispatch`. Consequently, only those *seven* methods should be called. Try using `__uuidof(DAO::_DBEngine)` as the interface request in your `CoCreateInstance()` invoke.